# Unable to snap after upgrading windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm not able to use my snap view anymore after changing from CP to RP windows 8. Anyone know the problem? Seems like Virtualstate isnt responding

```
<Page x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="World_Clock.MainPage"
    IsTabStop="false"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:World_Clock"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Viewbox x:Name="viewbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" Stretch="UniformToFill">

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="764" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1353" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" IsVerticalRailEnabled="False">

            <Grid x:Name="maingrid" Height="auto" Width="auto">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/wp2.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="134" Margin="1025,358,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="204" Fill="#FFCCE1CC"/>
               etc...
                </Grid>
<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="324" Source="Assets/Logo.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="1464,0,-422,0"/>

            </Grid>

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Viewbox>

<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="grid1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="70,500,0,0"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="grid2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="48,900,0,-164"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

<VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>

    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


</Page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good news!

Tested your XAML and the app snapps

```
<Page
x:Class="App4.MainPage"
IsTabStop="false"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App4"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Viewbox x:Name="viewbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" Stretch="UniformToFill">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="764" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1353" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" IsVerticalRailEnabled="False">
        <Grid x:Name="maingrid" Height="auto" Width="auto" Background="white">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="134" Margin="1025,358,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="204" Fill="#FFCCE1CC"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Viewbox>

<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="grid1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="70,500,0,0"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="grid2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="48,900,0,-164"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Can it be that you are running on a too low resolution? Check the resolution, snapping function does not work below 1366 I believe.

Good luck! Let me know how it goes and what the problem was!

Comment: Its i had to put the code inside the grid tag for it to work! Thanks anyway